# XML element reordering not working XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to reorder elements in a XML using XSLT 1.0. Below is small snippet of the XML

```
<RIMSDB1 xmlns="http://kiris.nps21.org/xsd">
    <ROW>
        <ReportID>1</ReportID>
        <WKYMD>20160610</WKYMD>
        <RunSystemDate>20160610032048</RunSystemDate>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <ReportID>2</ReportID>
        <WKYMD>27869</WKYMD>
        <RunSystemDate>495876043985778649</RunSystemDate>
    </ROW>
```

This is the XSLT I am using to transform it.

```
<xsl:template match="*/ROW">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="WKYMD" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="RunSystemDate" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportID" />
</xsl:copy>
```

Issue is when I transform I get no change in order but I remove xmlns="http://kiris.nps21.org/xsd" from

```
<RIMSDB1 xmlns="http://kiris.nps21.org/xsd">
```

I get correct transformation, which is:

```
<RIMSDB1>

    <ROW>
    <WKYMD>20160610</WKYMD>
    <RunSystemDate>20160610032048</RunSystemDate>
    <ReportID>1</ReportID>
</ROW>
    <ROW>
    <WKYMD>27869</WKYMD>
    <RunSystemDate>495876043985778649</RunSystemDate>
    <ReportID>2</ReportID>
</ROW>
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening of if there is a better way to reorder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your source document contains `xmlns="http://kiris.nps21.org/xsd"` then all of your elements (without a namespace prefix, or overriding namespace declaration) will inherit that namespace and are bound to the namespace `http://kiris.nps21.org/xsd`. It is sometimes difficult to notice or understand when there is no namespace-prefix.

You should adjust your XSLT to declare that namespace with a prefix and then adjust the select and match expressions to use the namespace prefix in order to properly address those elements.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:k="http://kiris.nps21.org/xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*/k:ROW">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="k:WKYMD" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="k:RunSystemDate" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="k:ReportID" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Mads-That worked for me but I ran into some other issue. How do handle this with namespace in both parent and child tags, eg

`<RIMSDB1 xmlns="http://kiris.nps21.org/xsd">
 <EDDP_CSI_ADJPORTINVEST_HSTY xmlns="">
  <ROW>
   <ReportID>1</ReportID>
   <WKYMD>20160610</WKYMD>
   <RunSystemDate>20160610032048</RunSystemDate>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
   <ReportID>2</ReportID>
   <WKYMD>27869</WKYMD>
   <RunSystemDate>495876043985778649</RunSystemDate>
  </ROW>
 </EDDP_CSI_ADJPORTINVEST_HSTY>
</RIMSDB1>`

Comment: In that example, the elements with xmlns="" are being put in the "no namespace", and now it and it's descendants are NOT in the namespace declared in the document element. For those in the "no namespace", you don't use a namespace prefix in your select/match expressions.

Comment: If your input is not standard and you aren't sure when/which namespace the elements will be bound to, you could use a more generic match expression that only cares about the local-name() and does not care about the namespace-uri(). For instance *[local-name()='WKYMD']